# imagemagick: how to use the %[fx:...] operator in draw rectangle command?

Tags: shell, image-processing, terminal, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I can do this to draw a red rectangle on an image:

`convert original.png -fill red -draw "rectangle 10,20 150,40" result.png`

The 150,40 is the right bottom coordinate. However if I use the `%[fx:...]` operator in there, like so:

`convert original.png -fill red -draw "rectangle 10,20 %[fx:w-30],40" result.png`

The `%[fx:w-30]` is supposed to evalute to the image's width minus 30.

However I'm getting an error:

> convert: non-conforming drawing primitive definition `rectangle' @ error/draw.c/DrawImage/4227.

I have also tried single quotes (') instead of double (") but that made no difference.

My imagemagick version is 7.0.7-36.

What am I doing wrong? What's the correct way of using the `%[fx:...]` operator in the above example?

Comment: With ImageMagick 7 you should be using "magick" instead of "convert".

Comment: @GeeMack Thanks, never heard of that before. My convert version says 7.0.7-36 but apparently there's a difference between `convert` and `magick`. Anyway, it works, thanks!

Comment: Using convert in IM 7 typically calls IM 6. IM 6 does not support %[fx...] computations in line in most commands. You can use convert in IM 7 if you set up a symbolic link to magick.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to @GeeMack the solution is: use `magick` instead of `convert`, so it becomes:

`magick original.png -fill red -draw "rectangle 10,20 %[fx:w-30],40" result.png`

Answer (score 0):

If you're still on ImageMagick 6, you can use the `identify` command to output a formatted string and then use that in the `convert` command. Using shell syntax, this can be expressed as follows:

```
convert original.png -fill red -draw "$(identify -format 'rectangle 10,20 %[fx:w-30],40' original.png)" result.png
```

Answer (score 0):

> Tested works ImageMagick 6 & 7

Alternatively, you can use `info:` special format specifier in `convert` to evaluate the computations for you.

```bash
convert original.png -fill red -draw "$(convert original.png -format 'rectangle 10,20 %[fx:w-30],40' info:)" result.png
```